# Implementing Custom Adorners around Polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I am having a hard time adding **adorners to the corners of a Polygon**. Of course by corners I imagine at each point location.

This Microsoft page describes how but I am having a hard time understanding how to use their complete example. Can anyone please show me how to adapt?

Thank you very much.

[image: sample]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview

```
// Adorners must subclass the abstract base class Adorner.
public class SimpleCircleAdorner : Adorner
{
  // Be sure to call the base class constructor.
  public SimpleCircleAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
    : base(adornedElement) 
  { 
  }

  // A common way to implement an adorner's rendering behavior is to override the OnRender
  // method, which is called by the layout system as part of a rendering pass.
  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
  {
    Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

    // Some arbitrary drawing implements.
    SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    renderBrush.Opacity = 0.2;
    Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy), 1.5);
    double renderRadius = 5.0;

    // Draw a circle at each corner.
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
  }
}
```

Here's my code that adds the Polygon to the Canvas.

```
Polygon myPolygon;
private Polygon drawPolygon()
{

    //Add the Polygon Element
    myPolygon = new Polygon();

    // Appearance
    myPolygon.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightCoral;
    // Disabled for hit testing on border only.
    //myPolygon.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
    myPolygon.StrokeThickness = 6;

    // Alignment
    myPolygon.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myPolygon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    // Point Array for polyline.
    // This will come from an XML file.
    Point[] polylinePoints = {

        // START: @ TOP LEFT
        new Point(200.0F, 200.0F),

        // 1ST LINE: TOP RIGHT
        new Point(400.0F, 200.0F),
        // 2ND LINE: BOMTTOM RIGHT
        new Point(400.0F, 400.0F),
        // 3RD LINE: BOTTOM LEFT
        new Point(200.0F, 400.0F),

        // END: @ TOP LEFT
        //Not Required to close the Polygon...
        //new Point(200.0F, 200.0F),

    };

    // Load from Point[Array] polylinePoints.
    PointCollection myPointCollection = new PointCollection(polylinePoints);

    //myPointCollection.Add(Point1);

    // Add from PointCollection myPointCollection
    myPolygon.Points = myPointCollection;

    return myPolygon;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have tried to implement custom adorner around polygon and add the  Polygon to Canvas panel. For this, you have used this **SimpleCircleAdorner** class as per mentioned in the Microsoft page. I think, in this class you have passed the default size of Canvas panel. The default desiredsize value will be 0 points.

```
 Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);
```

If you want to implement custom adorner around polygon, you can set the height and width of canvas panel or pass the points in this **SimpleCircleAdorner** class of **OnRender** methods properly. I have tried your polygon points in this **SimpleCircleAdorner** class of **OnRender** methods,

**SimpleCircleAdorner code:**

```
        Point[] polylinePoints = {
            // START: @ TOP LEFT
            new Point(200.0F, 200.0F),
            // 1ST LINE: TOP RIGHT
            new Point(400.0F, 200.0F),
            // 2ND LINE: BOMTTOM RIGHT
            new Point(400.0F, 400.0F),
            // 3RD LINE: BOTTOM LEFT
            new Point(200.0F, 400.0F),
        };
        // Load from Point[Array] polylinePoints.
        PointCollection myPointCollection = new PointCollection(polylinePoints);

        // Draw a circle at each corner.
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, myPointCollection[0], renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, myPointCollection[1], renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, myPointCollection[2], renderRadius, renderRadius);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, myPointCollection[3], renderRadius, renderRadius);
```

**Loaded Event:**

```
        private void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var polygonColl = drawPolygon();
            polygonTL = polygonColl;
            canvasTL.Children.Add(polygonTL);
            var myAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(canvasTL);
            myAdornerLayer.Add(new SimpleCircleAdorner(canvasTL));
        }
```